# how to obfuscate reflection code using Zelix klassMaster tool

Tags: java, reflection, obfuscation

I'm using the Zelix KlassMaster evaluation version and now has a problem with the refection feature.As my program will load a class  which is defined in a xml file (for example,  com.xxx.xxx.A), and I hava defined
" accessedByReflection    com.xxx.xxx.A; " in the ZKM script .But when I run my program, it is still failed. The error is "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.xxx.A  " . I wonder whether my ZKM script is written correct or 
the  evaluation version don't support the refection feature.
   So how can I  obfuscate the reflection classes and meanwhile my program can find the new class name after obfuscation? where and how the mapping information is stored and loaded when the class is running?

my ZKM script is like as following：

```
classpath   "ZKM.jar"
            "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar"
            "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar"
            "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar"
            "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar"
            "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar"
            "classes/obfuscate/*"
            "classes/Non_obfuscate/*";

open        "/home/xxx/target/classes/*"
            "classes/obfuscate/*";

exclude     public *.*^ containing {public static main(java.lang.String[])} public static main(java.lang.String[]);

obfuscate   changeLogFileIn=""
            changeLogFileOut="ChangeLog.txt"
            obfuscateFlow=light
            exceptionObfuscation=light
            encryptStringLiterals=enhanced
            mixedCaseClassNames=ifInArchive
            aggressiveMethodRenaming=true
            collapsePackagesWithDefault=""
            localVariables=delete
            lineNumbers=delete
            autoReflectionHandling=normal
            obfuscateReferences=none
            obfuscateReferenceStructures=inSpecialClass;

accessedByReflection    com.xxx.xxx.A;

saveAll     archiveCompression=all "output";
```

Comment: Some obfuscators will support reflection but only if the class names are in the source. Class.forName("example.class") will work. The text will be seen and updated since it is statically accessible. Class.forName(getName()) will not work since the method call to getName()'s cannot be assessed statically. You will have to manually update the names in your xml file after running obfuscation. Zelix should be able to export the mappings file in its options. This file will tell you the before and after names for each class/method/field.

Comment: you are right.Thanks again.@Dank Vader